# Power LED from 240v AC

Tags: power-supply, led, ac, dc

I want to make a led glue stick lamp but i want it to power from 220-240v ac.
See link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=faNXVuPnZIE
As all time 9v battery will be costly for me so i want to do this.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a design, nor even electronic question.  Actually, it isn't even a question.

Comment: if you don't care about flicker, you can just use a series resistor. a capacitive dropper would provide smoother output.

Comment: Bro i don,t know about the flicker, series resistor or capacitive dropper can you please explain me.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that from the lack of information in your question, your electronics knowledge and experience is currently limited?

**If this is the case please dont 'play' with 220VAC**

I would suggest finding a suitable mains-powered 'wall wart' power supply. You should be able to use any one which gives sufficient current and voltage for your LED setup - and where you dont have 9V from the adapter you can change the resistor values to suit - many many free calculators for LED / Resistor online :)